# Override default SQL generation in EF 6 based on entity type

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Having a typical entity class

```
public class MyTable {
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

EF generates something like this:

```
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.MyTable",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
```

I'd like to inherit some of my entity classes from an interface `IMyInterface`:

```
public interface IMyEnterface {}
```

Then I want to override the default generation so that the migration *for any class implementing* `IMyInterface` automatically looks like this:

```
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.MyTable",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)

    Sql(@"EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty bla-bla-bla");
```

Is there any extension point in EF 6.2 to allow that?

Comment: You can write your own migration operations. You might be able to leverage that to make it at least somewhat easier on yourself though I don't know if you'll get it automatically based on interface. See here for two examples. https://romiller.com/tag/migrationoperation/ (reviewing them, you might be able to add some reflection to detect the interface inside the Up method perhaps)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 you should post that as an answer!

Comment: @MichalCiechan I would if I knew enough about it. I only just by chance read those articles over the weekenr after clicking a link in another SO comment. I know almost nothing about EF

Answer (score 1):

More easier to do it at `Seed` method:

```
var tables = context.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(x => 
        x.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments
        .Any(y => typeof(IMyEnterface).IsAssignableFrom(y))
        );

foreach (var table in tables)    
    if(sp_NotExecutedYet(table))
        context.Database
           .ExecuteSqlCommand($"EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty {propertyNameFor(table)}");
```

Comment: This is a good option, thank you. **ef-enum-to-lookup** extension we use in our project does something similar to generate FKs to enum-tables. This increases seed time though so I still hope for a way to do it in migrations.